# C++ equivalent of XML selectnodes from C#

Tags: c++, xml

Say for example I have a sample of xml data like below. How can I collect the nodes of type **name** in c++ using tinyxml? Or is tiny xml not the ideal library to use? You can see in the sample code below I can easily do this in c#. I'm just not clear on how to do this in tinyxml or if it's even possible.

Xml

```
<Names>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <LastName>White</LastName>
    </Name>
</Names>
```

[C#]

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

The output is:

```
Name: John Smith
Name: James White
```

Comment: Since `SelectNodes()` accepts XPath string parameter, maybe try TinyXML + [TinyXPath](http://tinyxpath.sourceforge.net/) (disclaimer: I'm not a C++ user)

Comment: Have a look to libxml2 orl libxml++

Answer (score 0):

TinyXML requires you to traverse the DOM manually. As har07 mentioned, if you want XPath support you could give [TinyXPath](http://tinyxpath.sourceforge.net/) a try.